# SMPP Recived PDU

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway, smpp, jsmpp

I am trying to implement PHP SMPP http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1373-PHP-Sends-SMS-messages-via-an-SMPP-server.html  and trying to get the delivery receipts, but i am unable to read.   Below is the PDU response that i am getting.

Highly appreciate your help.

```
Trying to read PDU.
Reading PDU : 32 bytes.
Stream len : 28
Stream Hex : 80 00 00 05 00 00 00 0d 00 00 00 02 55 6e 6b 6e 6f 77 6e 20 63 6f 6d 6d 61 6e 64 2e 

Command id : 5.
Command status : 13.
sequence_number : 2.
GOT deliver_sm.

Received PDU: 
€(0)(0)(5)(0)(0)(0)(13)(0)(0)(0)(2)Unknown command.

Total number of count(sms) SMS= 1
Array
(
    [service_type] => 
    [source_addr_ton] => 0
    [source_addr_npi] => 0
    [source_addr] => Unknown command.
    [dest_addr_ton] => 
    [dest_addr_npi] => 
    [destination_addr] => 
    [esm_class] => 
    [protocol_id] => 
    [priority_flag] => 
    [schedule_delivery_time] => 
    [validity_period] => 
    [registered_delivery] => 
    [replace_if_present_flag] => 
    [data_coding] => 
    [sm_default_msg_id] => 
    [sm_length] => 
    [short_message] => 
)
GÃ¶nderildiSending PDU, len == 16
Sending PDU, header-len == 16
Sending PDU, command_id == 6
Sending PDU, sequence number == 3
Sending PDU, command status == 0
```

Comment: Correct my if I am wrong. I am assuming (1) You are connected as ESME (2) You previously sent a SMS requesting delivery receipt (3) You are trying to read delivery receipt. Can you post the PDU you sent requesting delivery receipt?

Comment: Yes, I am connecting as ESME.   2) Yes,   3) Yes.
Sending PDU, len == 16 Sending PDU, header-len == 16 Sending PDU, command_id == 21 Sending PDU, sequence number == 2 Sending PDU, command status == 0 Trying to read PDU. Reading PDU : 16 bytes. Stream len : 12 Stream Hex : 80 00 00 15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 Command id : 21. Command status : 0. sequence_number : 2. GOT enquire_link_RESP.

Comment: Sending PDU, command status == 0 Trying to read PDU. Reading PDU : 23 bytes. Stream len : 19 Stream Hex : 80 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 46 33 39 30 34 45 00 Command id : 4. Command status : 0. sequence_number : 3. Got submit_sm_RESP. message id : F3904E. Received PDU: €(0)(0)(4)(0)(0)(0)(0)(0)(0)(0)(3)F3904E(0)